# A weak condition for normality of a subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Is it true that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ iff $\forall g\in G \exists x\in G : gN=Nx$?

I don't think so, but I can't think of a counterexample obviously if $N$ is normal then the above condition is satisfied, since then $x=g$, but how about the other direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $g \in gN = Nx$. But right cosets are a partition of $G$ and $g \in Ng$. Hence $gN = Nx = Ng$ for all $g \in G$ and $N$ is normal.